# RECURRING contribution and auto-renew membership

Tags: civimember, contribution-page, price-sets

I am trying to setup an optional but **recurring** donation/contribution on a membership signup *Contribution Page*. Ideally, the new member will also have an option to choose frequency of payment, but we can do without.
[image]

I have tried price sets with a second membership for a "dummy" organisation for the donation bit, but it doesn't seem to give me an option for BOTH to be recurring.

I have also tried activating membership contribution and Contributions Amount on the campaign page, (without price sets) but as soon as I activate recurring contributions, I get the following error:
[image]

When I then enable separate payments from the membership tab, I get the error

> You cannot enable both Recurring Contributions and Auto-renew memberships on the same online contribution page.

Has anyone got a workaround? Any help and guidance towards the right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: Adding this as a comment and I may be able to come back later and answer this fully but, if you're on drupal, you might be able to achieve this with webform civicrm, rather than a contribution page as webforms now supports [recurring contributions](https://www.drupal.org/node/2557997#comment-11840715). Are you on drupal?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Drupal, then webform_civicrm can indeed mix and match different monies [Membership + Contribution + Event] and since recently construct a recurring series as well. There are some differences though compared to how each of these individual bits work using CiviCRM Core itself:

- you will add up all components using webform elements -> to get a
  Total $ amount;
- you can then present to the user (or config them
  yourself) - how you want these to be paid (now, monthly installments,
  etc)
- you end up with one payment - and since CiviCRM Core is not really expecting that this is possible, you won't see the distribution of that payment in the backend. So a $100 contribution + $50 Membership will show $150 payment both on the Contribution screen as well as on the Membership screen.

Comment: No the totals are still ok! The monies add up just fine it's just the display issue;

Comment: So there is only one $150 payment 